# Read JsonNode into a pre-existed POJO

Tags: java, json, jackson

currently I'm doing this to convert `JsonNode` to a POJO:

```
try {
    MyClass obj = mapper.treeToValue(jsonData, MyClass.class)));
    /* consume obj */
} catch (JsonProcessingException ex) {
    return false;
}
```

But sometimes I don't want to get a new instance of `MyClass`. I have have populated it before and now I just want to set new values for some fields and keep old values for unchanged fields. What I want is something like this: `mapper.readJsonNodeToPOJO(jsonData, obj)));` Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Why don't you add an inner object inside MyClass that maps the node?

Comment: @inigoD I don't understand your comment, can you explain a bit more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `ObjectMapper.readerForUpdating` method. Similar question has been asked [here](http://jackson-users.ning.com/forum/topics/deserialization-into-an) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12518618/deserialize-json-into-existing-object-java)

Answer (score 0):

You can do an inner custom object:

```
public class MyClass{
  MyNode node:
  ....
}

public class MyNode{
   .....
}
```

This way you can do:

```
MyClass obj = mapper.treeToValue(jsonData, MyClass.class)));
```

and:

```
obj.setNode(mapper.treeToValue(jsonSubData, MyNode.class))
```