# How to tell Jackson deserialize update value on non-missing fields include nested fields

Tags: java, json, jackson

I've Foo class with some values and use the same Foo oject to deserialize.

```
public class Foo {
        public String name;
        public Integer age;
        public Goo g;
}
static public class Goo {

        public Long id;
        public Integer level;
}

assume // String jsonStr = {"name" : "alan"; "g": {"level":6}}
Foo f = new Foo();
f.name = "dummy";
f.age = 99;
//asssume f.g.id = 3
objectMapper.readerForUpdating(f).readValue(jsonStr);
// f object toString
output {"name" : "alan"; "age" : 99, "g":{"id": null, "level":6}}
```

how to configure such that it wont upate any or default value on the field which have value on the missing field?

like below output instead

```
output {"name" : "alan"; "age" : 99, "g":{"id": 3, "level":6}}
```

Comment: `=` is the assignment operator. How do you expect Jackson to get the value 99 from the object previously refefenced by `f`?

Comment: yup, you are right. use readerForUpdating instead. it work. Thanks.

Comment: i've upated the question more specific.

Comment: I don't believe you can go that deep.

Comment: Yes, i can't . that's y i've i'm asking any possible way.

Answer (score 2):

You can configure the mapper manually or annotate the `Foo` class.

Manually:

```
objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);
```

Or put an annotation on the class (or even on the attribute):

```
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
public class Foo {
        public String name;
        public Integer age;
}
```

EDIT: this answers the question if you want to ignore nulls, but as a comment on the question say, you might have an error in your code. You re-assign your variable before reading, obviously

Comment: mayber my question not clear. Anyway, it is not the answer i'm looking. found answer from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12518618/deserialize-json-into-existing-object-java