# Java start reading Json with given starting object

Tags: java, json, jackson2

Let's consider the following object:

```
public class MyObject{
    int a, b;

    public MyObject(){
        setA(1);
        setB(1);
    }

    // getters and setters

}
```

I have the following string

```
{"a":4}
```

when I use Jackson 2 to create a new object I have `a = 4` and `b = 1` (I assume, it's the object created with the empty constructor where setters are used to modify the fields that Jackson 2 reads in the string).

Now, I have an instance of myObject with `a = 1` and `b = 2` (different from the one I can have with the empty constructor).
How can I use the String to "complete" the object to `a = 4` and `b = 2`?
In other words: how can I use an incomplete json string to replace field values in an already existing object different from the one created with the empty constructor?

EDIT: a possible solution from answer.

```
public static Object updateObject(String fileName, Object oldValue){
    try {
        return new ObjectMapper().readerForUpdating(oldValue).readValue(new File(fileName));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return oldValue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to deserialize into already existing object.
In that way your constructor will be called only once.

See documentation on [ObjectMapper.readerForUpdating](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#readerForUpdating(java.lang.Object)) .
This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12518618/2417043) may also help.