# Exposed: How to parse JSON into an Entity class

Tags: json, kotlin, gson, kotlin-exposed

I have the following user table object & entity class:

```
object UserTable : IntIdTable() {
    val name = varchar("name", 256)
}

class User(id: EntityID<Int>): IntEntity(id) {
    companion object : IntEntityClass<User>(UserTable)
    val name by UserTable.name
}
```

Is there a way to use Gson (or some other library) to parse JSON
into a `User` instance, and then insert it? From what I can tell,
it seems like I'll have to create an intermediate `UserData` data class and then manually copy the fields over.

```
data class UserData {
  var id: Int?
  var name: String?
}

fun main() {
  val data = Gson().fromJson<UserData>("...", UserData::class.java)
  val user = User.new {
    name = data.name
  }
}
```

It's not that bad in this contrived example, but I'm wondering if there's a dry'er approach.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Exposed does not allow creating DAO objects by yourself because you always need to pass an `EntityID` to the constructor. However, [Jackson supports reading an existing object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20153790/3755692). So, you can write something like this:

```
transaction {
    User.new {
        mapper.readerForUpdating(this).readValue(json)
    }
}
```

To make sure that Jackson and Exposed don't interfere, you'll have to create your `mapper` like this:

```
val mapper by lazy {
    val mapper = jacksonObjectMapper()
    mapper.setAnnotationIntrospector(object : JacksonAnnotationIntrospector() {
        override fun hasIgnoreMarker(m : AnnotatedMember)
            =  (m.getDeclaringClass() == IntEntity::class.java)
            || (m.getDeclaringClass() == Entity::class.java)
            || super.hasIgnoreMarker(m)
    })
    mapper
}
```

Also note that you cannot put `@JsonProperty` annotation on delegated properties but you must use `@get:JsonProperty`.

In order to use Jackson, add the following to your `build.gradle` file (if you are not using gradle, you'll have to adapt that code to your build system):

```
compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin:2.9.0"
```

---

Here is a fully working example: https://gist.github.com/msrd0/1d8d3d76de4010cc72868d8a36f0560a

Comment: I'm getting https://gist.github.com/icholy/ee3d16875b2de07bd2769ac8912ecffb also, I am unable to add the `@JsonProperty()` annotation to delegated properties.