# How to re-use DAO class of Exposed for JSON serialization or transfering data?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-exposed

Recently I try to learn Kotlin by writing a `Kotlin + Exposed` demo.

Common steps using `Java + MyBatis` would be: creating Java Bean class, mapper class, service class and service implementation class

```java
@Data class UserBean { String username; String password; }
@Mapper interface UserMapper extends BaseMapper<UserBean> {}
interface UserService extends BaseService<UserBean> {}
@Service UserSerivceImpl extends BaseServiceImpl<UserBean> implements UserService {}
```

Then those Java Bean classes are used in any other parts of system for database IO and JSON serialization.

```java
// create instance and convert to JSON
var user = new UserBean();
user.setUsername("username");
user.setPassword("password");
var om = new ObjectMapper();
var json = om.valueToTree(user);
```

Following [official doc of Exposed DAO API](https://github.com/JetBrains/Exposed/wiki/DAO), I create those classes:

```kotlin
class User(id : EntityID<Int>) : IntEntity(id)
{
    companion object : IntEntityClass<User>(Users)
    var username by Users.username
    var password by Users.password
}
object Users : IntIdTable()
{
    val username = varchar("username", 64)
    val password = varchar("password", 64)
}
```

When performing database IO, `User.all()` and `User.new { }` api work well. But creating instance directly would throw an exception:

```kotlin
// get data from JSON or somewhere else
val username = ...
val password = ...
// trying to create instance
val id = EntityID(-1, User.table) // trying to create an empty ID. I don't know if this is allowed
val user = User(id)
user.username = username // this would throw exception
user.password = password
```

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Property klass should be initialized before get.
    at kotlin.properties.NotNullVar.getValue(Delegates.kt:62)
    at org.jetbrains.exposed.dao.Entity.getKlass(Entity.kt:34)
    at org.jetbrains.exposed.dao.Entity.setValue(Entity.kt:198)
```

[Post here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48162305/9907751) says *Exposed does not allow creating DAO objects by yourself*. So is there a easy way to re-use those DAO classes for JSON serialization or transfering data between parts of program? Should I create a DTO class with identical data fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exposed Entities are stateful objects. You shouldn't serialize them directly. Instead, as you mentioned, you should use a simple data class with serialization annotations relevant to you.

For example:

```kotlin
class User(id : EntityID<Int>) : IntEntity(id)
{
    companion object : IntEntityClass<User>(Users)
    var username by Users.username
    var password by Users.password

    fun asResponse(): UserResponse {
        return UserResponse(username, password)
    }
}

@Serializable
data class UserResponse(val username: String, val password: String)
```

Comment: So this means we HAVE to write the same data structure for twice? Exposed has no annotation processing tool or something like that helps us do this job?

Comment: Correct. Exposed is a DB framework. It has nothing to do with how your HTTP responses are serialized.

Answer (score 1):

The best way i have tried to solve this issue is by writing 2 extension functions

```kotlin
import org.jetbrains.exposed.dao.Entity
import org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.SizedIterable
import kotlin.reflect.full.declaredMembers

inline fun <reified Dao: Entity<*>, reified Response> Dao.toResponse() : Response = this::class.declaredMembers.let { doaParameters ->
    val response = Response::class
    val responseObjectParameters = Response::class.constructors.first().parameters
    response.constructors.first().call(
        *responseObjectParameters.map { responseParam ->
            doaParameters.find { it.name == responseParam.name }?.call(this)
        }.toTypedArray()
    )
}

inline fun <reified Dao: Entity<*>, reified Response> SizedIterable<Dao>.toResponse() : List<Response> = this.map { doa ->
        doa::class.declaredMembers.let { doaParameters ->
            val response = Response::class
            val responseObjectParameters = Response::class.constructors.first().parameters
            response.constructors.first().call(
                *responseObjectParameters.map { responseParam ->
                    doaParameters.find { it.name == responseParam.name }?.call(doa)
                }.toTypedArray()
            )
        }
    }
```

this can be executed on all result of the transactions and return a data class or a list of dataclass

The type variables are:
Dao: The entity class
Response: Dataclass representing the data

examples:

```kotlin
class TestDao(id: EntityID<Int>) : IntEntity(id) {
    companion object : IntEntityClass<TestDao>(TestTable)
    var sequelId by TestTable.sequelId
    var name     by TestTable.name
    var director by TestTable.director
}

data class TestResponse(
    var sequelId: Int,
    var name: String,
    var director: String
)

@Router("api/Account")
class Account{
    @Get
    fun testGet() : ResponseEntity<List<TestResponse>> = transaction {
        val parsed = TestDao.all().toResponse<TestDao, TestResponse>()
        ResponseEntity.ok(parsed)
    }

    @Get
    fun testGet(@PathParameter id: Int) : ResponseEntity<TestResponse> = transaction {
        val parsed = TestDao.findById(id)?.toResponse<TestDao, TestResponse>() ?: throw NotFoundException("No entity found with id: $id")
        ResponseEntity.ok(parsed)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My previous anwer was fine to use with data classes that only contained basic typed veriables and did not handle other sorts of types.

For the people that are intrested, I did a complete overhaul of the code and it now works with custom types and classes.
And also with referenced data base entries.

The way to use the functionality is still the same as the previous code

```
import io.ktor.util.reflect.*
import org.jetbrains.exposed.dao.Entity
import org.jetbrains.exposed.dao.IntEntity
import org.jetbrains.exposed.dao.id.EntityID
import org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.LazySizedCollection
import org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.SizedIterable
import kotlin.reflect.KType
import kotlin.reflect.jvm.jvmErasure

inline fun <reified Dao: Entity<*>, reified Response> Dao.toResponse() : Response = this::class.members.let { doaParameters ->
    val response = Response::class
    val responseObjectParameters = Response::class.constructors.first { !it.parameters.any { it.name == "serializationConstructorMarker" } }.parameters
    response.constructors.first { !it.parameters.any { it.name == "serializationConstructorMarker" } }.call(
        *responseObjectParameters.map { responseParam ->
            doaParameters.find { it.name == responseParam.name }?.let { doaParameter ->
                when{
                    doaParameter.call(this)?.instanceOf(EntityID::class) ?: false -> (doaParameter.call(this) as EntityID<*>).value
                    doaParameter.call(this)?.instanceOf(IntEntity::class) ?: false -> (doaParameter.call(this) as Entity<*>).handleObject(responseParam.type)
                    doaParameter.call(this)?.instanceOf(LazySizedCollection::class) ?: false -> (doaParameter.call(this) as LazySizedCollection<Entity<*>>).handleList(responseParam.type)
                    doaParameter.call(this)?.instanceOf(SizedIterable::class) ?: false -> (doaParameter.call(this) as SizedIterable<Entity<*>>).handleList(responseParam.type)

                    else -> doaParameter.call(this)
                }
            }
        }.toTypedArray()
    )
}

inline fun <reified Dao: Entity<*>, reified Response> SizedIterable<Dao>.toResponse() : List<Response> = this.map { dao ->
    dao::class.members.let { doaParameters ->
        val response = Response::class
        val responseObjectParameters = Response::class.constructors.first { !it.parameters.any { it.name == "serializationConstructorMarker" } }.parameters
        response.constructors.first { !it.parameters.any { it.name == "serializationConstructorMarker" } }.call(
            *responseObjectParameters.map { responseParam ->
                doaParameters.find { it.name == responseParam.name }?.let { doaParameter ->
                    when{
                        doaParameter.call(dao)?.instanceOf(EntityID::class) ?: false -> (doaParameter.call(dao) as EntityID<*>).value
                        doaParameter.call(dao)?.instanceOf(LazySizedCollection::class) ?: false -> (doaParameter.call(dao) as LazySizedCollection<Entity<*>>).handleList(responseParam.type)
                        doaParameter.call(dao)?.instanceOf(SizedIterable::class) ?: false -> (doaParameter.call(dao) as SizedIterable<Entity<*>>).handleList(responseParam.type)
                        doaParameter.call(dao)?.instanceOf(IntEntity::class) ?: false -> (doaParameter.call(dao) as Entity<*>).handleObject(responseParam.type)
                        else -> try {
                            doaParameter.call(dao)
                        } catch (e: Exception){
                            dao.handleObject(responseParam.type)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }.toTypedArray()
        )
    }
}

fun <Dao: Entity<*>> Dao.handleObject(responseParam: KType) : Any = this::class.members.let { doaParameters ->
    val response = responseParam.jvmErasure
    response.constructors.first { !it.parameters.any { it.name == "serializationConstructorMarker" } }.call(
        *response.constructors.first { !it.parameters.any { it.name == "serializationConstructorMarker" } }.parameters.map { responseParam ->
            doaParameters.find { it.name == responseParam.name }?.let { doaParameter ->
                when{
                    doaParameter.call(this)?.instanceOf(EntityID::class) ?: false -> (doaParameter.call(this) as EntityID<*>).value
                    doaParameter.call(this)?.instanceOf(LazySizedCollection::class) ?: false -> (doaParameter.call(this) as LazySizedCollection<Entity<*>>).handleList(responseParam.type)
                    doaParameter.call(this)?.instanceOf(SizedIterable::class) ?: false -> (doaParameter.call(this) as SizedIterable<Entity<*>>).handleList(responseParam.type)
                    doaParameter.call(this)?.instanceOf(IntEntity::class) ?: false -> (doaParameter.call(this) as Entity<*>).handleObject(responseParam.type)
                    else -> doaParameter.call(this)
                }
            }
        }.toTypedArray()
    )
}

inline fun <reified Dao: Entity<*>> LazySizedCollection<Dao>.handleList(responseParam: KType): List<*> = this.wrapper.map { daoEntry ->
    val response = responseParam.arguments.first().type!!.jvmErasure
    response.constructors.first { !it.parameters.any { it.name == "serializationConstructorMarker" } }.call(
        *response.constructors.first { !it.parameters.any { it.name == "serializationConstructorMarker" } }.parameters.map { responseParam ->
            daoEntry::class.members.find { it.name == responseParam.name }?.let { doaParameter ->
                when{
                    doaParameter.call(daoEntry)?.instanceOf(EntityID::class) ?: false -> (doaParameter.call(daoEntry) as EntityID<*>).value
                    doaParameter.call(daoEntry)?.instanceOf(IntEntity::class) ?: false -> (doaParameter.call(daoEntry) as Entity<*>).handleObject(responseParam.type)
                    doaParameter.call(daoEntry)?.instanceOf(LazySizedCollection::class) ?: false -> (doaParameter.call(daoEntry) as LazySizedCollection<Entity<*>>).innerList(responseParam.type)
                    doaParameter.call(daoEntry)?.instanceOf(SizedIterable::class) ?: false -> (doaParameter.call(daoEntry) as SizedIterable<Entity<*>>).innerList(responseParam.type)
                    else -> try {
                        doaParameter.call(daoEntry)
                    } catch (e: Exception){
                        daoEntry.handleObject(responseParam.type)
                    }
                }
            }
        }.toTypedArray()
    )
}

inline fun <reified Dao: Entity<*>> SizedIterable<Dao>.handleList(responseParam: KType): List<*> = this.map { daoEntry ->
    val response = responseParam.arguments.first().type!!.jvmErasure
    response.constructors.first { !it.parameters.any { it.name == "serializationConstructorMarker" } }.call(
        *response.constructors.first { !it.parameters.any { it.name == "serializationConstructorMarker" } }.parameters.map { responseParam ->
            daoEntry::class.members.find { it.name == responseParam.name }?.let { doaParameter ->
                when{
                    doaParameter.call(daoEntry)?.instanceOf(EntityID::class) ?: false -> (doaParameter.call(daoEntry) as EntityID<*>).value
                    doaParameter.call(daoEntry)?.instanceOf(IntEntity::class) ?: false-> (doaParameter.call(daoEntry) as Entity<*>).handleObject(responseParam.type)
                    doaParameter.call(daoEntry)?.instanceOf(LazySizedCollection::class) ?: false-> (doaParameter.call(daoEntry) as LazySizedCollection<Entity<*>>).innerList(responseParam.type)
                    doaParameter.call(daoEntry)?.instanceOf(SizedIterable::class) ?: false-> (doaParameter.call(daoEntry) as SizedIterable<Entity<*>>).innerList(responseParam.type)
                    else -> try {
                        doaParameter.call(daoEntry)
                    } catch (e: Exception){
                        daoEntry.handleObject(responseParam.type)
                    }
                }
            }
        }.toTypedArray()
    )
}

fun LazySizedCollection<Entity<*>>.innerList(responseParam: KType) = this.handleList(responseParam)

fun SizedIterable<Entity<*>>.innerList(responseParam: KType) = this.handleList(responseParam)
```