# NodeJS: How to populate / overwrite an object with the values from a similar object

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, object, schema

.

#### globalscope.json:

```js
"object1": {
    "thing1": "",
    "thing2": "",
    "thing3": ""
},
"search": {
    "tracking": {
        "crawl": false,
        "index": true
    }
}
```

#### localscope.json

```js
"object1": {
    "thing1": "some",
    "thing2": "new",
    "thing3": "data"
},
"search": {
    "tracking": {
        "crawl": true, /* !! It should update the booleans etc */
        "index": true
    },
    "somethingnew": 777 /* !! new values would be awesome but not essential */
}
```

.

I found what looks to be a solution using C#, but I need JS / Node please.

I'm looking for an agnostic tool, although defining a schema in the beginning would be ok too.

- [Overlay data from JSON string to existing object instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5157079/overlay-data-from-json-string-to-existing-object-instance)

.

Comment: It needs to update all the similar properties in the first object?

Comment: if the second object doesn't have them declared as blank, yes

Comment: You mean blank like ""? In that case you need to do it manually with recursion.

Comment: You're essentially merging two objects. There's a popular package to do that, deepmerge. https://www.npmjs.com/package/deepmerge

Comment: i figured it would be a popular thing, just didn't think of searching "merge"

Answer (score 0):

You could combine two objects with the rest operator (`...`) which works similar to Object.assign

Example:

```
const obj1 = {
  a: 2,
  b: 3,
  h: 10
}

const obj2 = {
  b: 11,
  a: 12
}

const obj3 = {...obj1, ...obj2}
```

The result would be

```
{a: 12, b: 11, h: 10}
```

Comment: hmm its close. :)

Comment: @user9779523 notice the above comment, you could have problem with nesting in future. Use npm package 'deepmerge' with customMerge if you'll have problems with simple resting.